# React App Is In Development Mode After Deploying

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux

I deployed my react app to Heroku and it is running in development mode so redux-logger is shown in the console. Not sure if it's important, but I used create-react-app. Also, I didn't manually create a server.

Here is my [package.json](https://github.com/moizes86/My-Hompage/blob/master/package.json).

App is [Here](https://mm-homepage.herokuapp.com/homepage).

Comment: You should *build* the app and deploy the *result* to Heroku. You can use the node buildpack to create the outputs and static file buildpack to serve them. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe.

Comment: As suggested by @jonrsharpe, you need to build the app and deploy those assets with any server you wish. You can simply deploy that on any static site hosting platform like Netlify, or even create a NodeJS server and host on Heroku

Comment: Thanks to both of you - I did deployed build folder to netlify. I am sorry I can't rate your comments, I will do so when it will be possible. Thanks for your help.